# How to round a Geodjango Distance

Tags: python, django, distance, geodjango

In Django 1.9 / Python 2.7, I have the following view:

```
qs = ThePlace.objects.filter(lnglat__distance_lte=(lnglat, D(km=30))).distance(lnglat).order_by('distance')
```

In my template, I display the distances when I loop over the objects:

```
{% for qsplace in qs %}
    {{ qsplace.distance }}
{% endfor %}
```

which displays "25.717617095 m" for example.

I would like to display rounded figures (26 m). If more than 1 km, I would like to display 3 km for example

I have developed a first templatetag to round the figures:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def dividebyth(value):
    print(type(value))
    value = round(value, 2)
    return value
```

And put in my template:
    {{ qsplace.distance|dividebyth }}

which results in the following error:

```
TypeError: a float is required
```

It seems I cannot round a Distance object.

Any way to manage that ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance):

> Because the `distance` attribute is a `Distance` object, you can easily express the value in the units of your choice. For example, `city.distance.mi` is the distance value in miles and `city.distance.km` is the distance value in kilometers.

To get distance value as float in meters try this: `{{ qsplace.distance.m|dividebyth }}`

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks